# My computer's VS2010 C# Project's Reference's Property field points to an Older version of System.Activites.dll

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

Here is the problem: I downloaded my solution from my team's TFS. But I am the only one in the team that gets this message:

> The Type or Namepspace Name StateMachine not found (are you missing ...)

When trouble shooting I found out that, in that specific project where I get the error, when looking at Properties of System.activities under Project References the Path filed points to an older version of the `System.activities.dll` but all my teammates' Path points to the newer version of the `System.activities.dll`. Something is out of sync in my machine and I cant figure out what. My Registry Keys, my VS2010 version, are the same software as the teammates have but I still get the above error.

I don't know why the Path on my Properties for `System.activities` is pointing to the older version of the `System.activities.dll` - what am I missing? I even checked the Machine.Config under the latest .NET install on my machine and it looks the same (just glancing at it) as the rest of the teammates.

Any help would be appreciated.  If I need to reinstall should I reinstall VS2010, .NET and the whole nine yards ?

Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the [.NET Framework 4 Platform Update 1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee264171.aspx). It comes in two downloads:

1. [The runtime update](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2478063): Needed for running WF4 StateMachine workflows. Install this on the computer that runs your application and on your development machine
2. [The design time update](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2495593): Needed for design time support of WF4 StateMachine workflows. Install this on your development machine if you want to edit StateMachine workflows.

The reason is that .NET 4 didn't ship with a StateMachine workflow. It was added later and made available via the aforementioned Platform Update 1

Comment: Thanks.  I think that is already downloaded to my machine by the Admin, but how do I make sure I have it before re-installing it again??

Comment: To clarfy I do see C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319on my machine

Comment: @user1298925: What path is it showing on your machine and what path is it showing on the machine of your team mates?

Comment: My path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Activities.dll    My teammate path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0.1\System.Activities.dll

Comment: @user1298925: Do you have the path `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0.1` on your machine?

Comment: Yes, if you mean do I see that directory existing on my machine?  yes I do see it. But although I downloaded from the same TFS server as my teammates the Path on the Property field for them points to 4.0.1 but mine points to 4.0??

Comment: @user1298925: BTW: v4.0.30319 is the version of the "normal" .NET Framework 4.

Comment: @user1298925: That is strange. Try to remove the reference on your machine and add it again. Which version of the file do you have? Which version do your team mates have? Have you verified that the file `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0.1\System.Activities.dll` has the same version on your computer as it has on your team mates computer?

Comment: Well, while trying your suggestion remove and add I found out that the .NET tab in Add Reference looks for System.Activities.dll in v4.0 directory !!!!! I don't know how to change that?  Something is out of sync on my machine. Although when I click Add reference a th the top I do see that it is filtered to:.NET Framework 4 Platform Update 1.

Comment: @user1298925: I suggest you re-install the Platform Update 1

Comment: ok, I will do that.  I will let you know what happend.  Thanks so far for your help.

Comment: Thank you a milliion times for your fantatsic support and follow through.  Doing what you suggested in your initial answer worked. Thanks.